# 3 tables SQL query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have three tables:

```
niveis(id, descricao)
formacoes(id, id_nivel, nome)
formacoes_professores(id, id_professor, id_formacao)
```

I'd like to run a query that returns the education levels(niveis) with the number of professors that has it.

I'm running this query:

```
SELECT n.descricao, count(f.id_nivel)
FROM niveis_de_formacao n
LEFT OUTER JOIN formacoes f
ON (n.id = f.id_nivel)
GROUP BY n.descricao
```

And I'm getting this results:

```
descricao   count
Mestrado    0
Graduação   2
Doutorado   0
Especialização  0
```

It seems like what I'm trying to do. But in this query I'm just counting the number of courses that a education level has. 
What can I do to query the `formacoes_professores` table and count how many professors a education level has.

For example, if three professors have the same course (lets assume it is a masters degree), the query needs to return:

```
Mestrado   3
```

But in the query I'm running, instead of three, I'll get `Mestrado  1`, because it is the same course.

Thanks.

Comment: Try editing your question and including sample data.  Your query looks correct.  If the value for "Mestrado" is 0, the data would not seem to contain anything at that level.

Comment: Ok, but I'm counting the number of courses an education level has. What I need to do is to count the number of `professores` an education level has. For example, if three professors has the same course, the query should return three in that level, but in the query I'm running it'll return 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you simply need to add a join? and make the counts distinct?

```
SELECT n.descricao, count( distinct f.id_nivel), count( distinct fp.id_professor)
FROM niveis_de_formacao n
LEFT OUTER JOIN formacoes f
  ON (n.id = f.id_nivel)
LEFT OUTER JOIN formacoes_professores fp 
  ON f.id = fp.id_formacao
GROUP BY n.descricao
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked! I didn't understand it yet, but it worked. I'll look deeply, thanks.

Comment: The join took brings in the professors which you didn't have in your original query, the distinct counts are necessary otherwise the formacoes would be duplicated per professor artificially increasing the counts thus the need for distinct there as well.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're trying to also get the professor count. I recommend using a derived table that has the professor count and left joining it.

```
SELECT t1.* , COALESCE(t2.cnt,0) professor_count
FROM (
    SELECT n.id, n.descricao, count(f.id_nivel) education_count
    FROM niveis_de_formacao n
    LEFT OUTER JOIN formacoes f
    ON (n.id = f.id_nivel)
    GROUP BY n.id, n.descricao
) t1 LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT count(*) cnt, f.id_nivel
    FROM formacoes_professores fp
    JOIN formacoes f ON f.id = fp.id_formacao
    GROUP BY id_nivel
) t2 on t2.id_nivel = t1.id
```